# Testing Vuex Actions with API calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to test a simple Vuex action that fetches data through an API call. What I am having the most trouble figuring out is how to mock that call. The way I'm currently doing it feels wrong, but I'm not sure where else to go.

I have tried abstracting the axios call into a service to make it more similar to the Vuex boilerplate but that yielded the same result. The rest of the code is identical to the Vuex docs on testing actions - [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/testing.html).

**action**

```
//actions.js 

export default {
  getData({ commit }) {
    return axios.get(__API__ + 'test/', {
      headers: auth.getAuthHeader(),
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      commit('getData', response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  },
};
```

**mock**

```
//actions.spec.js

const url = __API__ + 'test/';
// create the module with our mocks
const actions = actionsInjector({
  url: {
    getData () {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const arr = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish', 'Snail']
        resolve(arr)
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**helper function**

```
// utils.js  

const testAction = (action, payload, state, expectedMutations, done) => {
  let count = 0;

  // mock commit
  const commit = (type, payload) => {
    const mutation = expectedMutations[count];
    try {
      expect(mutation.type).to.equal(type);
      if (payload) {
        expect(mutation.payload).to.deep.equal(payload);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }

    count++;
    if (count >= expectedMutations.length) {
      done();
    }
  }

  // call the action with mocked store and arguments
  action({ commit, state }, payload);

  // check if no mutations should have been dispatched
  if (expectedMutations.length === 0) {
    expect(count).to.equal(0);
    done();
  }
}

export default testAction;
```

**test case**

```
// actions.spec.js

it('it has an action that gets data', done => {
  testAction(actions.getData, [], {}, [
    { type: 'getData',  payload: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish', 'Snail'] }
  ], done)
});

error: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'action({ commit: commit, state: state }, payload)')
testAction@index.js:19858:9
index.js:19813:25
```